# Displaying image from separate java file

Tags: java

I am trying to load a random image from a separate class file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class random { 
    static String back01;

    public static void ran(int number) {
        switch(number) {
            case 1:
                setImage("images/01.jpg");
                break;
            case 2:
                setImage("images/02.jpg");
                break;
            case 3:
                setImage("images/03.jpg");
                break;
            case 4:
                setImage("images/04.jpg");
                break;
            case 5:
                setImage("images/05.jpg");
                break;
            case 6:
                setImage("images/06.jpg");
                break;
            case 7:
                setImage("images/07.jpg");
                break;
            case 8:
                setImage("images/08.jpg");
                break;
            case 9:
                setImage("images/09.jpg");
                break;
            case 10:
                setImage("images/10.jpg");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid number");
        }
    }

    public static void setImage(String back01) {
        String image = back01;
    }

    public static int getImage() {
        String test;
        String set = setImage(test);
        return set;
    }
}
```

I am getting stuck on how to call the function to my main class, whatever I do I keep getting an incompatible types error when compiling. If it helps until I am home to access my usb with a backup of the code I have, I will post a block of code that is relevant to this execution.

```
int number = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
random.ran(number);
```

I then tried to put it to an imageicon using

```
.getResource(random.getImage());
```

Then it would through an error saying that I couldn't have a void in that function
Here is my main function, finally have access to my code.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class main here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

JButton start, exit;

static String back, back01;

Random rand = new Random();

private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;
//private StartButtonHandler sbHandler;
public test()
{
    int test = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

    random.ran(test);

    /*switch(rand_background)
    {
        case 1:
            back = "images/01.jpg";
            break;
        case 2:
            back = "images/02.jpg";
            break;
        case 3:
            back = "images/03.jpg";
            break;
        case 4:
            back = "images/04.jpg";
            break;
        case 5:
            back = "images/05.jpg";
            break;
        case 6:
            back = "images/06.jpg";
            break;
        case 7:
            back = "images/07.jpg";
            break;
        case 8:
            back = "images/08.jpg";
            break;
        case 9:
            back = "images/09.jpg";
            break;
        case 10:
            back = "images/10.jpg";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }

    int rand_background01 = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;*/



    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
    //sound.music("music/theme01.wav");

    String testing = random.getImage() + "";

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(random.getImage()));

    //ImageIcon image01 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(back01));

    start = new JButton("Start game...");
    exit = new JButton("Exit game...");

    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    background.setIcon(image);
    background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel background01 = new JLabel();
    //background01.setIcon(image01);
    //background01.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add(background);
    //panel.add(background01);

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    panel.setOpaque(false);

    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

    exit.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    panel.add(start);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));
    panel.add(exit);


    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    test menu = new test();

}
}
```

With this code I am trying out very basic procedural generation by changing the background for now. As I go it will be more complex but as of right now we don't have any tiles created yet so I can't go much more in depth with the code until I have something to experiment with.

EDIT:

I managed to get it to work, but I had to remove my setImage method. Is there a way to incorporate this back into it? It looked a lot better in my code than this

```
/**
 * Write a description of class random here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class random
{
public static String back01;
public static void ran(int number)
{
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
            back01 = "images/01.jpg";
            break;
        case 2:
            back01 = "images/02.jpg";
            break;
        case 3:
            back01 = "images/03.jpg";
            break;
        case 4:
            back01 = "images/04.jpg";
            break;
        case 5:
            back01 = "images/05.jpg";
            break;
        case 6:
            back01 = "images/06.jpg";
            break;
        case 7:
            back01 = "images/07.jpg";
            break;
        case 8:
            back01 = "images/08.jpg";
            break;
        case 9:
            back01 = "images/09.jpg";
            break;
        case 10:
            back01 = "images/10.jpg";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
}

public static void setImage(String back01)
{
    back01 = random.back01;
}

public static String getImage()
{
    return random.back01;
}
}
```

When I would try using System.out.println(random.getImage()) i would get null with and without the random in front of back01

EDIT/SOLVED:

I figured it out! Thank you all for your guidance. Here is how I fixed the setImage function.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class random here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class random
{
public static String back01;
public static String test;
public static void ran(int number)
{
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
            setImage("images/01.jpg");
            break;
        case 2:
            setImage("images/02.jpg");
            break;
        case 3:
            setImage("images/03.jpg");
            break;
        case 4:
            setImage("images/04.jpg");
            break;
        case 5:
            setImage("images/05.jpg");
            break;
        case 6:
            setImage("images/06.jpg");
            break;
        case 7:
            setImage("images/07.jpg");
            break;
        case 8:
            setImage("images/08.jpg");
            break;
        case 9:
            setImage("images/09.jpg");
            break;
        case 10:
            setImage("images/10.jpg");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
}

public static void setImage(String back01)
{
    test = back01;
}

public static String getImage()
{
    return test;
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your main class' code. Please also follow Java naming conventions and capitalize the first letter of class names. Though you might want to rename `Random` to something like `RandomImage`, since there is already the Java built in `java.math.Random` class.

Comment: I was testing random things to try to get it to work within the 3 minutes I had before class ended. I will edit my main post to include my main function when I get home. I will rename everything when I put it in my actual program. I created a separate program to test my experimental code and ideas before putting them into the actual program. I had it working when it was in the switch statement was in my main function but didn't like the repetition so wanted a new class to deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Random 
{ 
    private String back01;

    public static void ran(int number) {
        switch(number) {
            //All options
        }
    }

    //If you only use "setImage()" in the class is not necessary
    //declare this one as "public static"
    //public static void setImage(String back01) {
    private void setImage(String back01) {
        this.back01 = back01;
    }

    public static String getImage() {
        return back01;
    }
}
```

Then to prove it:

```
int number = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
random.ran(number);
.getResource(random.getImage());
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. Finally tried out your code. When I try to compile it I get an error in the public static void ran saying "non-static method setImage(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context". All other code seems to work. When trying to compile from the main file it goes back to this error

Comment: I got it to compile making the string and all methods public static, I also removed "this" in "this.back01 = back01". Now I am getting an error in my main file, Java.lang.NullPointerException: null (in sun.misc.MetaIndex) when I call random.getImage()

Answer (score 0):

Why is your method attempting to return a String when the method signature shows the return type to be an int ?

```
    public static int getImage() {
       String test;
       String set = setImage(test);
       return set;
    }
```